# WITH clause behavior in BEGIN END block PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I run the following it executes just fine

```
WITH temp AS ( SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables )
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

When I then add a BEGIN-END block it does not work anymore

```
BEGIN
    WITH temp AS ( SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables )
    SELECT * FROM temp;
END;
```

The error message is:

> an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Can anyone explain what is going on here and why the WITH statement needs to be amended?

Comment: It's not the `WITH` clause. You would get this self-explanatory error for any `select` without an `into` clause.

Comment: When you run `SQL` statement under the scope of `PLSQL` engine, you need variables to hold the result of select statement and you capture those using `INTO` clause.